# is_file or file_exists in PHP

Tags: php, file, exists

I need to check if a file is on HDD at a specified location ($path.$file_name).

Which is the difference between [`is_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) and [`file_exists()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) functions and which is better/faster to use in PHP?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

`is_file()` will return `false` if the given path points to a directory. `file_exists()` will return `true` if the given path points to a valid file *or* directory. So it would depend entirely on your needs. If you want to know *specifically* if it's a file or not, use `is_file()`. Otherwise, use `file_exists()`.

Comment: as far as i know, if_file also fails for symbolic links, not only directories.

Comment: is_file() return true if file is exists in directory or false if file not exists as I check in 2020 might be php version update it

Comment: `file_exists()` could have been better named as `path_exists()`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099103/is-file-file-exists-performance-and-cache

Answer (score 42):

`is_file()` is the fastest, but recent benchmark shows that `file_exists()` is slightly faster for me. So I guess it depends on the server.

My test benchmark:

```
benchmark('is_file');
benchmark('file_exists');
benchmark('is_readable');

function benchmark($funcName) {
    $numCycles = 10000;
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numCycles; $i++) {
        clearstatcache();
        $funcName('path/to/file.php'); // or 'path/to/file.php' instead of __FILE__
    }
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
    echo "$funcName x $numCycles $time seconds <br>\n";
}
```

Edit: @Tivie thanks for the comment. Changed number of cycles from 1000 to 10k. The result is:

1. when the file *exists*:

   is_file x 10000 1.5651218891144 seconds

   file_exists x 10000 1.5016479492188 seconds

   is_readable x 10000 3.7882499694824 seconds
2. when the file *does not exist*:

   is_file x 10000 0.23920488357544 seconds

   file_exists x 10000 0.22103786468506 seconds

   is_readable x 10000 0.21929788589478 seconds

Edit: moved clearstatcache(); inside the loop. Thanks CJ Dennis.

Comment: in order for this benchmark to work, you should add clearstatcache(); since the results for is_file and file_exists are cached throughout the script. Anyways file_exists() is a bit slower, but shouldn't make any difference unless you perform around 100K file checks. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Comment: I too have found `is_file()` faster than `file_exists()`. If you know it's a file (and not a directory), definitely use it instead.

Comment: Odd, now it seems 'file_exists' is faster than 'is_file'.

Comment: Why are people interested in which is faster, because these two functions have different behaviours (as mentioned in the accepted answer, the one tests if it is a file or a symlink that points to a file (but not a directory and not a symlink which points to a directory) and the other tests if it is a file (which could also be a directory).

Comment: @Brandin People are interested because in many situations you **already know** if you're checking for a file or directory, so whether it exists is the only important thing. So if `is_dir()` turns out to be 20% faster than `file_exists()` (which it doesn't, btw), that can be an important difference if you're only checking for dirs anyway...

Answer (score 3):

Neither.

is_file() returns true if the file can be read.

file_exists() can return true if the file is a directory.

Note that in some edge cases file_exists() returns true when is_file() does not because of permissions or edge case filesystem issues where is_file() cant determine if its a "regular file".

Speed doesn't matter here because they are not the same and they will trade places in speed depending on circumstances.

Comment: Under what circumstances does `is_file()` return `true` if the file does not exist?

Comment: Finally came back and fixed it. Back when you commented I thought Id recreate the scenario and figure out how it was happening to me and post for all to see. Never got time and I haven't used php5 in years now, its probably never going to happen to anyone. A recent edit suggestion made me come back and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but the difference between this functions is not only their behaviours.
If you use is_file() to check the existence of big file, more than 2 Go. You will be surprise.
File not exists. :(
But if you check with file_exists(), that's works.

Answer (score 0):

`is_file` would be faster if use it with backslash: `\is_file`. In this case PHP will provide opcache optimization neither `file_exists` won't.