# Performance of is_file vs file_exists and caching in PHP?

Tags: php, performance

I made some tests to compare and measure speed of both functions. **is_file** seems to be several times faster (I used 10000 iterations for both) than **file_exists** . I wonder if PHP or OS use some cache for these functions or does is always access HDD ? I think no, but I wonder...

I used this code:

```
<?php
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$begintime = $time[1] + $time[0];
for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++)
    file_exists('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php');
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(" ", $time);
$endtime = $time[1] + $time[0];
$totaltime = ($endtime - $begintime);
echo 'PHP parsed this in ' .$totaltime. ' seconds.</br>';
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(" ", $time);
$begintime = $time[1] + $time[0];
for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++)
    is_file('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php');
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(" ", $time);
$endtime = $time[1] + $time[0];
$totaltime = ($endtime - $begintime);
echo 'PHP parsed this in ' .$totaltime. ' seconds.</br>';
?>
```

Comment: Are you calling this many times in a tight loop (where this effect will dominate the request time)?  If not, I wouldn't worry about it unless you're sure it's causing you a performance problem...  Remember that `Premature optimization is the root of all evil`...  Use the semantically better alternative until you know it's a problem and then optimize then and only then...

Comment: Indeed, is_file() is a whopping 10 times faster than file_exists()! Just tried it, and it's true.

Comment: If it helps to anybody we can add that file_exists() will return true for both directories and files that exist, where is_file() only will return true if it's a file (and exists, of course).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> When you use stat(), lstat(), or any
>   of the other functions listed in the
>   affected functions list (below), PHP
>   caches the information those functions
>   return in order to provide faster
>   performance. However, in certain
>   cases, you may want to clear the
>   cached information. For instance, if
>   the same file is being checked
>   multiple times within a single script,
>   and that file is in danger of being
>   removed or changed during that
>   script's operation, you may elect to
>   clear the status cache. In these
>   cases, you can use the
>   clearstatcache() function to clear the
>   information that PHP caches about a
>   file.
>
> Affected functions include stat(),
>   lstat(), file_exists(), is_writable(),
>   is_readable(), is_executable(),
>   is_file(), is_dir(), is_link(),
>   filectime(), fileatime(), filemtime(),
>   fileinode(), filegroup(), fileowner(),
>   filesize(), filetype(), and
>   fileperms().

Comment: But both functions are in that list, so that doesn't seem to explain why one would be much faster than the other.

Comment: You execute the `file_exists()` test first, which has to do the actual read from disk and store to statcache; then you execute the `is_file()` which simply reads the statcache entry that has already been populated by the `file_exists()` check, so it is (not surprisingly) a lot faster. Flush the cache between tests, and then you'll be testing `is_file()` accurately because it will have to check the disk and populate the cache in the same way that `file_exists()` did

Comment: Your reply ... was too damn slow. See to it that this is improved ;)

Answer (score 13):

PHP caches both `is_file()` and `file_exists()` in the stat cache.  Call `clearstatcache()` to clear it.

Edit:
If anything, the two should take similar amounts of time because they both call the OS's [`stat()` function](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/stat.html), but the results of one may be cached for the other by PHP (unless you `clearstatcache()`) or by the OS as Yuliy mentions below.

Comment: Note that performance measurements on file operations risk varying due to the operating system's file system cache

Comment: `strace` shows file_exists calls `access("foo", F_OK)` while `is_file` does `stat("foo", 0x7fffe720a8a0)`

Answer (score 1):

`is_file` and `file_exists` are two different function that does two different things; `file_exists` only check if the file exists, `is_file` tell if the target is a valid file, and (for example) not a directory.

They shouldnt be used for the same goal, so the performance comparison cant be done (imho)

Comment: this is not entirely correct. however the functions were designed, the goal is to achieve the desired result. in this case, both is_file() and file_exists() return false if the file doesn't exist. and the benchmarks prove that using is_file() will give your application an edge over a similar application using file_exists().

Comment: @stillstanding: But what kind of edge are we talking about?  Since the disk `stat()` is going to be the slowest part, I'd be surprised if the two differ by more than MAYBE one or two percent.  After all, both use the same data, one just returns sooner (and both should only be making one system call)...  At least that's my understanding of it anyway...

Comment: @stillstanding: Which benchmarks?  I would think `file_exists` would be slightly faster, as it doesn't have to check whether the [stat structure](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html)'s `mode_t` contains S_IFDIR or not.

Comment: Exactly @R. Bemrose... Pseudocode should be for `file_exists`: `return false !== stat()` and for `is_file`: `$stat = stat(); if ($stat !== false) { return ($stat['mode_t'] & S_IFREG) != 0; } return false`...  So `is_file` should be slower (but not much, since the `stat()` will still dominate the other simple language constructs)...

Comment: is_file() checks only if the arg is a file. file_exists() checks whether the arg is a file OR a directory. the speed should come out even if the file/folder in both functions do not exist.

Comment: A quick benchmark on my system (calling `clearstatcache()` shows that they are both within a margin of error of each other (about 1% difference on average)...  So (at least on my ext3 filesystem) there's really little difference (since as expected the `stat()` system call dominates the time)...  And for the record `file_exists()` doesn't check if it's a file or a directory, it just checks that the filesystem object exists (and doesn't care what type, it could be a block device for all it cares, just that something by that name exists)...

Comment: try to run PHP code I used for test and post results, it shows me big difference between both functions

Comment: @stillstanding: i can not agree with your first comment. If you need if something exists on your drive, go with `file_exists`. If you need to know if the target is a valid file, go with `is_file`, you'll gain readability and reliability of code.  What happens if noather developer (team work?) read your code? Or when you'll need to edit the code years laters? If i see `is_file` i guess the environment need to know if is a real file, and use it accordingly. Why build up incomprension for gain what - 0.001 ms? But im going off topic i guess.

Comment: @DaNieL: It's not off-topic.  It's a very bad paradigm of micro-optimization.  Killing readability and semantic correctness for ever-so-slight gains in speed (when it's not even known if that speed gain is needed)...  `It's easier to optimize correct code than to correct optimized code`...

Comment: @ircmaxell: that's exaclty what i mean

Comment: Actually I have seen a performance test that concluded that `is_file` is actually faster. Also people in the WP world use it all the time even if the actually want to know if a file exists but despite its name `if_file_exists` also will return true on directories that are called `directoryname.php` so I was thinking everyone is doing it wrong, the function name is horrible given the fact that it does ... and opted to use `is_file` for checking if files exists. It would be interesting if it was and is really faster now in a php7 world.