# How to include a file only if the file exists in PHP?

Tags: php

I need an `include` function / statement that will include a file only if it exists. Is there one in PHP?

You might suggest using `@include` but there is an issue with that approach - in case the file to be included exists, PHP will not output warnings if the parser find something wrong in the included file.

Comment: Are you asking for something different than these answers are giving you? I'm having a hard time believing you know `@` and `include()` but not `file_exists()`.

Comment: @JMC Creative, I'm aware of the `file_exists()` approach. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792899/is-file-or-file-exists-in-php

Answer (score 101, accepted):

```
if(file_exists('file.php'))
    include 'file.php';
```

That should do what you want

Comment: Or without the conditional in a single line: `file_exists($file) AND include $file;`...

Comment: Better to use `is_file`, which would avoid directories - for safer code.

Comment: @hakre I think I fixed that by combining it with StephaneJAIS's answer.

Comment: @ircmaxell can you provide a link for that?

Comment: This won't work if the current working directory is different than the include path. `file_exists` is relative to the current working directory, but `include` doesn't necessarily check the current working directory.

Answer (score 9):

Try using [`file_exists()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.file-exists.php)

```
if(file_exists($file)){
  include $file;
}
```

Comment: New link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 8):

Based on @Select0r's answer, I ended up using

```
if (file_exists(stream_resolve_include_path($file)))
    include($file);
```

This solution works even if you write this code in a file that has been included itself from a file in another directory.

Comment: This is misleading. `stream_resolve_include_path` means it looks in the PATH for the file (or more specifically, relative to each element of the PATH). This is *not* the same thing as relative to the file in which the `include` is written

Answer (score 3):

How about using `file_exists` before the `include`?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [`stream_resolve_include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-resolve-include-path.php) function.

Answer (score 3):

```
@include($file);
```

Using at in front, ignores any error that that function might generate.
Do not abuse this as IT IS WAY SLOWER than checking with if, but it is the shortest code alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use `file_exists`, because if there was such an include, it would have been listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

the `@` suppresses error messages.

you cloud use:

```
$file = 'script.php';
if(file_exists($file))
  include($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting these as an answer since they were discussed in comments:

```
if(is_file($file)) {
  include $file;
}
```

Or:

```
is_file($file) AND include $file;
```

This is theoretically [faster and also safer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792899/is-file-or-file-exists-in-php) than using `file_exists` because it skips right to using the simple test `is_file` without having to check whether it's a file vs folder, etc, and it also will never load a folder (potentially unsafe).

Here's a brief example:

```
<?php
$file = "test.txt";
if(is_file($file)) {
  echo ("$file is a regular file");
} else {
  echo ("$file is not a regular file");
}
?>
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_is_file.asp

Answer (score -2):

```
function get_image($img_name) {
    $filename = "../uploads/" . $img_name;
    $file_exists = file_exists($filename);
    if ($file_exists && !empty($img_name)) {
        $src = '<img src="' . $filename . '"/>';
    } else{
        $src = '';
    }
    return $src;
}
echo get_image($image_name);
```