# How to position boxes?

Tags: css

I have two files, one is called header.php and other one is called index.php.

header.php looks like this:

```
<div class="long_box">**Small long box**</div>
```

index.php looks like this:

```
<?php
include('header.php');
?>

<div class="content">**Big box**</div>
```

and this is the CSS file:

```
.long_box {
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    width:200px;
    min-height:400px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fefefe; }
.content {
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    width:515px;
    min-height:800px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fefefe; }
```

So I am using "long_box" in header.php, "content" in index.php and then including header.php in index.php which gives me this page: http://gyazo.com/5bb4375f05ff5c9b3c3f8c47e7d3a0c0.png

Now, I want to add a third box all the way on the right side, like in this image where the red box is: http://gyazo.com/ea2f330cab8cc07508fa797a2ad5de3e.png

I want to include the third box each time I decide to include header.php.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: `<div style="content">**Big box**</div>` should read `<div class="content">**Big box**</div>`

Comment: My bad, was a typo here on the website but it's class in the file.

Comment: Can't you just create another div in `header.php` and float it right? Or all left.

Comment: I tried that but the third box doesn't float to the right after the big box, it goes under the long small box :/

Comment: Did you `float` them too?

Comment: Yes, I tried to float it too, but it doesn't go to the right, it goes under the long line.

Comment: Right try this... Left box `float:left;` content box `margin: 0 auto;` (do NOT float) right box `float: right;`

Answer (score 0):

You can just float the 3 boxes with `float: left;`

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FYzpc/1)

Whenever one of the floated elements goes underneath an other floated element, it might be because your third box does not fit on the screen.

*Note that i used an other `width` so it would fit on my screen*

**Update**

Whenever your element that should positioned at the far right is called first. You can use `float: right;`

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FYzpc/3/)

Comment: That works, but how would I position the third box all the way to right if I call the third box in header.php?

Comment: In this case you want to call the selector of that element(for example: id or class) and use `float: right;`. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: So in other words, what I said ;)

Comment: @Ruddy oh, i did not see your comment :( i'll delete mine if you post an answer :)

Comment: I have already tried that but it doesn't work, the third box doesn't go right but it positions itself under the long box :(

Comment: Ah na its fine. You knew what you was on about too.

Comment: @user3049858 I have used the same layout before. It 100% does work as im still using it today.

Comment: @user3049858 When you really really can't figure out what is wrong, but then i mean you really see what i did and what you did. Then you can always make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and show us the full code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what your looking to do here is check if header.php is included and if so include your new box aside.php (or whichever).

You can try if file_exists like so:

```
if(file_exists('header.php'))
    include 'aside.php';
```

Found this here with more info, which may be useful to you:
[How to include only if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604965/how-to-include-only-if-file-exists)

PS. As cederlof said, also change your content attribute to class not style.

Answer (score 0):

okay...so here is **fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/DgsH3/

**header.php**

```
<div class="long_box">**Small long box**</div>
<div class="third_box"> Third box </div>
```

**index.php**

```
<div class="content">**Big box**</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.long_box {
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    width:18%;
    min-height:400px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fefefe; 
    float:left;
}


.third_box{
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    width:18%;
    min-height:400px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fefefe; 
    float:right;

}


.content {
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    width:40%;
    min-height:100%;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fefefe; 
    margin:0 auto;

}
```

using %age for width...its a better idea considering responsive designs!! ;)

Comment: @user3049858 : is your content in divs dynamic??