# Check if image file exists in another server

Tags: php, file

I work on two servers (A and B, and I need to show on A some images from B. The problem is I need to test if the image exists (else I show only the name of the client).

When I test in local, this works:

```
 if (file_exists(http://www.example.com/images/3.jpg)) {
     // I show the file here
 } else {
     // I just show the name
 }
```

But, that's don't works now. Help please !

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to check if image file exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991425/php-how-to-check-if-image-file-exists)

Comment: This sounds like the file_exists method does not exactly do what you want it to do. In order to encourage users to help you, it might be helpful if you post the code of this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `file_exists` for a checking remote files.

Use `get_headers` function and check, if the file returns `200` or not.

```
$file_headers = get_headers('http://www.example.com/images/3.jpg');

if ($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {
    echo "The file exists";
} else {
    echo "The file doesn't exist";
}
```

Comment: Being probably over-cautious, but in the general case, neither the `1.1` nor the `OK` are absolutely guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

```
$array= get_headers("http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_ima.jpg");
   echo  $h= $array[0];
```

it will return **HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found**  if not exists and **HTTP/1.1 200 OK**  if exists

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_file_on_url_exists($url)
{
    if (@file_get_contents($url, 0, NULL, 0, 1))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

try this one out !!