# How to fix: Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.domain.com/assets/magento_img/18540_01.jpg):

Tags: magento, dataflow

We are trying to import some products into magento via Dataflow 
Advanced Profiles and are getting the below error. We have searched high and low but just cant find any answers on how to fix this issue. I am very hopeful that someone will be able to shed some light on this matter.

Please can anyone help fix this, we would be very grateful.

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.domain.com/assets/magento_img/18540_01.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Handler/Image.php on line 64

Here is the xml script we are useing.

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
    <var name="type">ftp</var>
    <var name="host"><![CDATA[000.00.00.00]]></var>
    <var name="passive">true</var>
    <var name="user"><![CDATA[username]]></var>
    <var name="password"><![CDATA[password]]></var>
<var name="path"><![CDATA[/]]></var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[feedname.csv]]></var>
    <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>

<action type="lanot_dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
<var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
<var name="enclose"><![CDATA[]]></var>
<var name="fieldnames">true</var>
<var name="_single_category_path">true</var>

    <var name="map">
        <map name="product_model"><![CDATA[sku]]></map>
        <map name="product_name"><![CDATA[name]]></map>
        <map name="product_description"><![CDATA[description]]></map>
        <map name="product_retail_price"><![CDATA[price]]></map>
        <map name="product_price"><![CDATA[cost]]></map>
        <map name="product_quantity"><![CDATA[qty]]></map>
        <map name="image_location"><![CDATA[image]]></map>
        <map name="IPG_Cat_Desc_1"><![CDATA[category_ids]]></map>
        <map name="IPG_Cat_Desc_2"><![CDATA[category_ids]]></map>
        <map name="product_brand"><![CDATA[manufacturer]]></map>
        <map name="product_barcode"><![CDATA[ean]]></map>

        <map name="@type"><![CDATA[simple]]></map>
        <map name="@attribute_set"><![CDATA[Default]]></map>
        <map name="@visibility"><![CDATA[Catalog, Search]]></map>
        <map name="@status"><![CDATA[Enabled]]></map>
        <map name="@tax_class_id">Taxable Goods</map>
        <map name="@websites">base</map>
        <map name="@weight">0</map>
        <map name="@short_description"><![CDATA[@description]]></map>
        <map name="@thumbnail"><![CDATA[@image]]></map>
        <map name="@small_image"><![CDATA[@image]]></map>
    </var>

    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="number_of_records">1</var>
    <var name="decimal_separator"><![CDATA[.]]></var>
    <var name="adapter"><![CDATA[catalog/convert_adapter_product]]></var>
    <var name="method">parse</var>
</action>
```

Comment: check for file permission?

Comment: can you be a bit more specific as I am very new to this. shall I check for folder permissions? which folder or file?

Comment: is your file accessible through url?

Comment: Yes we can access the file via the ftp url

Comment: I mean by web url. like `https://example.com/images/a/jpg`.

Comment: ah just checked that url and there is no file located at that location, how do I make it to skip that file and just import the rest?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per your comments this issue is due to image is not exist. So I suggest you to check first for the image. you can do that by simmply checking.

```
$file = "http://www.domain.com/assets/magento_img/18540_01.jpg";
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
```

or you can try

```
if (@getimagesize('http://www.domain.com/assets/magento_img/18540_01.jpg')) {
          // your code
    }
```

for more information [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#75064).

Comment: @Quentin : while I just recently visiting SO I found an answer with the same code. you should warn there too in case it is not working for HTTP

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991425/php-how-to-check-if-image-file-exists

Comment: where do I put the above code in i.e which file and path would be great, I am very new to magento.

Comment: check that with putting just above  `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Handler/Image.php on line 64`

Comment: if (!file_put_contents($targetPath . DS . $info['basename'], file_get_contents($imageUrl))) {
            return null;
        }

Comment: if (@getimagesize('http://www.domain.com/assets/magento_img/18540_01.jpg')) {
          // your code
    }

Comment: I tried on line 64 the below.

        if (@getimagesize('http://www.domain.com/assets/magento_img/18540_01.jpg')) {if (!file_put_contents($targetPath . DS . $info['basename'], file_get_contents($imageUrl))) {
            return null;
        }

Comment: the output of the window was the below

    Starting profile execution, please wait...
    Warning: Please do not close the window during importing/exporting data

But nothing is happening

Comment: I then tried the below code on line 64, it gave me a 504 Gateway Time-out nginx but before it would start and then the image missing error would come up

$file = "http://www.domain.com/assets/magento_img/18540_01.jpg";
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}if (!file_put_contents($targetPath . DS . $info['basename'], file_get_contents($imageUrl))) {
            return null;
        }

Comment: Its working, not sure what I did other then reinstalling centos 6 & plesk without the auto installer and increased max_execution_time & memory_limit. It is all working now, now need to get the other csv files to import into the site. thank you for the info and help, much appreciated.