# How do I loop through a multidimensional array to get a random image from each color?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am looking to loop through the array below and then populate a `<UL>` with 1 random image from each color array. I am having trouble getting my head around how to access the specific color arrays... Do I need a loop? Or would `array_rand()` be enough? How would I go about this?

```php
$colors = array( 
    'green' => array(
        'images/green1.jpg',
        'images/green2.jpg',
        'images/green3.jpg',
        'images/green4.jpg',
        'images/green5.jpg'
        ),
    'red' => array(
        '/images/red1.jpg',
        '/images/red2.jpg',
        '/images/red3.jpg',
        '/images/red4.jpg',
        '/images/red5.jpg'
        ),
    'blue' => array(
        '/images/blue1.jpg',
        '/images/blue2.jpg',
        '/images/blue3.jpg',
        '/images/blue4.jpg',
        '/images/blue5.jpg'
        ),
    'purple' => array(
        '/images/purple1.jpg',
        '/images/purple2.jpg',
        '/images/purple3.jpg',
        '/images/purple4.jpg',
        '/images/purple5.jpg'
        )
    );

<div>
    <span>Colors</span>
        <ul>
            <li>"1 img from 'green' array would go here"</li>
            <li>"1 img from 'red' array would go here"</li>
            <li>"1 img from 'blue' array would go here"</li>
            <li>"1 img from 'purple' array would go here"</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, [**array_rand()**](http://php.net/manual/function.array-rand.php) could be used, but you'll need to loop through the colors. For each one, get a random image:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($colors as $k=>$v){
    $arr[] = $v[array_rand($v)];
}

print_r($arr);
```

Output 1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => images/green3.jpg
    [1] => /images/red3.jpg
    [2] => /images/blue2.jpg
    [3] => /images/purple1.jpg
)
```

Running again:

```
Array
(
    [0] => images/green5.jpg
    [1] => /images/red3.jpg
    [2] => /images/blue1.jpg
    [3] => /images/purple4.jpg
)
```

---

If you want to output it like in the question, it would be something like this:

```
// div span ul
$arr = array();
foreach($colors as $k=>$v){
    echo '<li><img src="' . $v[array_rand($v)] . '"></li>';
}
// /div /ul
```

---

**Side notes:**

- The `green` urls from the array are missing the leading `/` (or every other color has a spare, I dunno);
- This codes does **not** check if the image exists ([file_exists](http://php.net/manual/function.file-exists.php) / [PHP: How to check if image file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7991425/4577762))

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I am looking for. Working with multidimensional arrays make my head hurt...

Comment: @airconductor, no problems. I'm glad to help. I know that the array seems quite formatted in the question, but doing an `echo '<pre>'; print_r($array_name); echo '</pre>';` helps a lot. At least it does for me...

Comment: Good advice, I will give that a try next time I am dealing with arrays. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($colors as $color){
    $image = array_rand($color);
    echo '<li>' . $color[$image] . '</li>';
}
```

Comment: You should always provide information behind your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would so something along the lines of

```
foreach ($colors as $color){
     //This gets you each color array in turn, in here you can 
     //use array_rand() to get a random entry from each array.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<?php
$colors = array(
'green' => array(
'images/green1.jpg',
'images/green2.jpg',
'images/green3.jpg',
'images/green4.jpg',
'images/green5.jpg'
),
'red' => array(
'/images/red1.jpg',
'/images/red2.jpg',
'/images/red3.jpg',
'/images/red4.jpg',
'/images/red5.jpg'
),
'blue' => array(
'/images/blue1.jpg',
'/images/blue2.jpg',
'/images/blue3.jpg',
'/images/blue4.jpg',
'/images/blue5.jpg'
),
'purple' => array(
'/images/purple1.jpg',
'/images/purple2.jpg',
'/images/purple3.jpg',
'/images/purple4.jpg',
'/images/purple5.jpg'
)
);
?>
<div>
    <span>Colors</span>
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach ($colors as $key=>$value){
            echo '<li>'.$value[array_rand($value,1)]."</li>";
        }
?>
    </ul>
</div>
```