# Get image JPG and jpg

Tags: php, image, jpeg, exists, file-exists

I've been bothered by this problem for a while now.
I'm trying to load images in PHP but there are jpg and JPG images and when I try to load images by jpg the JPG ones are not found (obviously)

```
$img1 = '<img src="imgs/'.$firstImage.'.jpg"></img>';
$img2 = '<img src="imgs/'.$secondImage.'.jpg"></img>';
$img3 = '<img src="imgs/'.$thirdImage.'.jpg"></img>';
$img4 = '<img src="imgs/'.$fourthImae.'.jpg"></img>';
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

I tried using `if_exists` but that didn't work out well

```
if (file_exists('http://website_url.nl/imgs/'.$firstImage.'.jpg')) {
    $img1 = '<img src="imgs/'.$firstImage.'.jpg"></img>';
} else  {
    $img1 = '<img src="imgs/'.$firstImage.'.JPG"></img>';
}
```

Problem now is that it can't find the images with regular jpg. For example I try to load `23.jpg` but the script tries to load `23.JPG` because the file `23.jpg` doesn't exist, while it does exist and is placed in the folder while `23.JPG` isn't. It works with the JPG files. For example `DOC_202.JPG` is found because `DOC_202.jpg` doesn't exist so it loads the `JPG` one. But with the `jpg` ones it won't work. Any solutions?

With kind regards,

Comment: Any chance of modifying the file when uploading them? So that the possible PHP script responsible for uploading converts everything to lower case. Or are files handled manually by someone else?

Comment: By files you mean the images? Well they emailed the images to me. And I just put them in the folder and upload them to the server

Comment: @Theekopje You can just rename them yourself  then right?

Comment: just  rename   the files to  be lowercase  or uppercase
on linux/unix  lowercase and uppercase letter  matter ,  while on  windows it is  the same.

Comment: Why are you trying to check, if the file exists with the full URL?

Comment: No i can't.. Well I can rename them but not the type of file from JPG to jpg. atleast I don't know how to. Tried looking it up but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Find a way to rename the images before uploading them, preferably in a script. Input sanitization is your friend.

Comment: @gre_gor [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991425/php-how-to-check-if-image-file-exists)

Comment: you  can  for sure rename them   on  linux host , but  it is quite hard to  do  on  windows. on window rename it to  something totally different  like aaa.bbb and then   back  to filename.jpg

Comment: any idea how to do this? @Joost

Comment: @Theekopje What OS are you running on your dev/uploading machine (not the server)? If you use Windows you need to do two steps to change the case of a file. First change `foo.JPG` into `foo.tmp.jpg` and then back to `foo.jpg`.

Comment: if I do that @Sergey it just says for example: DOC_202.jpg but when i check in the file properties the file is still JPG

Comment: Windows @h2ooooooo

Comment: @Theekopje As I just edited, make sure you rename your file first and THEN change the extension. Windows won't let you change the case of a file as it expects you didn't change anything so you need to force it to change it by changing something that isn't just case.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Ah, the wonderful quirks of Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for the file in your local directory, don't use the url

```
if(file_exists('imgs/'.$firstImage.'.jpg')) {
```

Most url wrapper don't support stat(), see
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php (blue note about php5 at the end) and http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

Edit:
PS: Side note, when using windows the directory separator is a backslash '\', on linux it's the forward slash '/'. See global constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` if you need a global solution.

Comment: This worked for me but I cant figure out why because [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991425/php-how-to-check-if-image-file-exists) suggested to use full link? But thanks!

Comment: That's weird. You should use the physical local address of the file.

Comment: @PerEnström It is the relative physical local file name, not the relative url. See my edit, linux (the server) uses forward slashes as directory separator

Comment: @clemens321 Yes, I was referring to the linked question by Theekopje. Not your answer!  :)

Comment: About using URL instead of physical address, check this comment on PHP.net: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#75064

Answer (score 0):

The function file_exists checks on the local system wether a file exists or not, not on the external URL.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

So if you change the file_exists parameter to your local address it should work. For example:

```
if(file_exists('/webdirectory/public_html/project/images/' . $image1 . '.jpg')){
    //do stuff
}
```

The case sensitiveness of file_exists depends on the file system it resides on. On unix servers file case matters, and so will file_exists.

This comment in the PHP manual suggests a way of checking via URL: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#75064