# How to check if an image exists in wodpress attachment

Tags: php, wordpress, image, lazy-loading

When I upload a very small 50x50px image then it is only as the original file (full size). How to check if an image exists. Thank you for your help.

```
if ($image_size == 'thumbnail'):
  $image_src = $image['sizes']['thumbnail'];
  $image_lazy = $image_src
if ($image_size == 'medium'):
  $image_src = $image['sizes']['medium'];
  $image_lazy = $image_src;
else: 
  $image_lazy = $image_src; //oryginal size ???
endif;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: How to check if image file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991425/php-how-to-check-if-image-file-exists)

Answer (score 0):

To check file exist in Php, Php has given us the function `file_exists(string $filename): bool`

```php
<?php
$filename = '/path/to/yourfile.jpg';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
?>
```