# I need my loop to stop when a file doesn't exist

Tags: php, loops

I have a set of related images in my `/images/` directory named sequentially as image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg etc...

I'm trying to output the images in my markup with PHP using a loop. But since the number of images varies, I need it to stop when it gets to the last image file in the directory.

Say I have 5 images, I want it to only output:

```
<img src="images/image1.jpg">
<img src="images/image2.jpg">
<img src="images/image3.jpg">
<img src="images/image4.jpg">
<img src="images/image5.jpg">
```

And if I add `image6.jpg` to the directory, it should automatically add to the markup. How do you do this?

**My current method**

```
for ( $i=1; $i<100; $i++ ) {

    if ( file_exists('http://localhost/images/image' . $i . '.jpg') ) {
        echo '<img src="http://localhost/images/image' . $i . '.jpg'">';
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys, added my current method in the edit

Comment: In an `else` clause, add a `break`. However if you don't know the number of images beforehand, then a `while` loop is better.

Comment: Or even better instead of checking whether a file exists check whether a file doesn't exist and break out of the loop. That way you don't need a `else`.

Comment: `if ( file_exists(...) ) {...} else break;`

Answer (score 3):

what about [`scandir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) ?

```
$dir    = '/images';
$imgs = scandir($dir);

foreach($imgs as $img)
{
  if($img != '.' && $img != '..')
  {
    echo '<img src="http://localhost/images/'.$img.'">';
  }
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest something like this. Just scan for existing files and output those.

Answer (score 3):

This snippet will generate the desired result:

```
$i = 1;
while(file_exists('./images/image' . $i . '.jpg')){
    echo '<img src="images/image' . $i . '.jpg">';
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a function called `file_exists()` for such an occasion.

Comment: Depending on my application, I often prefer is_file() instead. file_exists() will also return true for directories. http://stackoverflow.com/a/792909/924299

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

```
for ( $i=1; $i<100; $i++ ) {

    if ( file_exists('http://localhost/images/image' . $i . '.jpg') ) {
        echo '<img src="http://localhost/images/image' . $i . '.jpg">';
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

But you have an extra single quote in your example, so it's going to output:

```
<img src="images/image1.jpg'">
<img src="images/image2.jpg'">
<img src="images/image3.jpg'">
<img src="images/image4.jpg'">
<img src="images/image5.jpg'">
```

Comment: Good catch with the quote. Unfortunately it seems like `file_exists` doesn't understand URLs, so I have bigger problems.

Comment: gotcha. I guess asking what you're trying to do would be my next question. If you're trying to connect to a remote server, you can use cURL to grab them remotely. But if you can run the script on the same server, you can replace your for loop with a http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php or scandir like someone else suggested.